# Joining tables together via junction table in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering how to accomplish the same as a navigation property, when using three tables in a many-to-many relationship.

First I have some test code to get us starting:

```
var table1 = new[]
{
    new { Title = "Title1", Id = 1 },
    new { Title = "Title2", Id = 2 },
    new { Title = "Title3", Id = 3 }
};
var table2 = new[]
{
    new { GameId = 1, GenreId = 1 },
    new { GameId = 1, GenreId = 2 },
    new { GameId = 1, GenreId = 3 },
    new { GameId = 2, GenreId = 1 },
    new { GameId = 2, GenreId = 2 },
    new { GameId = 3, GenreId = 1 }
};
var table3 = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Genre1", Id = 1 },
    new { Name = "Genre2", Id = 2 },
    new { Name = "Genre3", Id = 3 }
};
```

"table1" contains some titles of say games for instance, "table3" contains some genres, and "table2" joins "table1" with "table3" by their ids.

Now my question is how do you most elegantly select a list of games (table1), each with a list of their genres (table3) into a list of anonymous types?

My solution so far is this:

```
var query =
    from t1 in table1
    select new
    {
        Game = t1,
        Genres =
        (
            from t2 in table2
            join t3 in table3 on t2.GenreId equals t3.Id
            where t2.GameId == t1.Id
            select t3
        ).ToList()
    };
var result = query.ToList();
```

Ideally I would like to avoid sub-queries, but the question is whether it can be avoided in this situation...

I was thinking something like this:

```
var query =
    from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.GameId
    join t3 in table3 on t2.GenreId equals t3.Id
    select new { Game = t1, Genres = t3 };
var result = query.ToList();
```

Which of course returns six items, which is not the result I want.

So to sum up: Is it possible in LINQ to select a list games (table1), each with a list of their genres (table3) without using sub-queries?

Comment: instead of `table1`, `table2`, `table3` why not `game`, `gameGenre`, `genre`?

Comment: Are you using EF or Linq to SQL generated classes in your project?

Comment: For my actual code yes, I am using EF, but the backend is a compact SQL database, which does not seem to support foreign keys... I am thinking about creating associations in the Entity model, but this question just bugged me. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you just want to combine your second query with a [`group by`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var query =
    from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.GameId
    join t3 in table3 on t2.GenreId equals t3.Id
    group t3 by t1 into g
    select new { Game = g.Key.Title, Genres = g.Select (x => x.Name) };
```

[image]

(*Note:* It should be obvious, but I just used `select new { Game = g.Key.Title, Genres = g.Select (x => x.Name) }` for illustration purpose. To select the actual types, use `select new { Game = g.Key, Genres = g }`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `group`:

```
var query =
    from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.GameId
    join t3 in table3 on t2.GenreId equals t3.Id
    group t3 by t1 into g
    select new { Game = g.Key, Genres = g.ToList() };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Now `result` is a list of anonymous type where `Game` is a thing from `table1` and `Genres` is a list of things from `table3`.